# Registered SSH Certificates in Windows

Tags: ssh, windows-8, certificate, putty, ssh-keys

I tried to connect to *Ubuntu Server* from *Windows 8* using *PuTTY*.

At first, it asked me some registration of key. I accepted the pop up request. After that whenever I access Ubuntu Server there will be no registration, because already registered.

What I want is I want that registered key from Windows 8 location and remove them, so that when try to connect PuTTY will ask me to register keys again.

I don't know **where those SSH keys or certificates are stored in Windows 8**. Please help me to find certificates and remove them. I tried my `C:\` I couldn't find any SSH folder or certificates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's called SSH host key. It's not a certificate.

PuTTY stores them to Windows registry under a key:

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\SimonTatham\PuTTY\SshHostKeys]
```

See [Verifying the host key](https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/latest/htmldoc/Chapter2.html#gs-hostkey) chapter in PuTTY documentation to understand the purpose and importance of verifying the SSH host key.

Comment: Thanks for reply.Am happy to receive answer from Author of some Technology.

Comment: I knew that,Am here for long time.Am checking location and your link mean  while.

Comment: Really Thanks.Update Vote with Acceptance.

Comment: But in my C:/ I coulnd't any folder with name of putty.In D:/ am having putty.exe ,On clicking that just it opens CUI for sign in to given host.I couldn't find any other place of folder for its keys storage.Sorry to disturb you.

Comment: Not sure if that's another question. Or do you just describe what have you tried before?